Implement Gestures with Animation over the LazyGrid Compose
I want to create a word-puzzle game, where the user creates words by moving over the grid of letters. I don't understand how to implement the vertical and horizontal moving (only these directions should be enabled) and select letters in the grid. For this time I have added only animation of the size when 'onDrag' method is called. I use Canvas and drawRoundRect to create a movable rectangular.The code I wrote:
@Composable
fun GameField() {
    var selectedWord by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var width by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    var height by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(6),
            modifier = Modifier,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(1.dp)
        ) {
            items(letters) { item ->
                LetterItem(
                    letter = item,
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    selectedWord = selectedWord,
                    onWordSelected = { selectedWord = it },
                )
            }
        }
        MovableRectangle(
            modifier = Modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDragStart = { offset ->
                            offsetX = offset.x
                            offsetY = offset.y
                        },
                        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                            width += dragAmount.x.toDp()
                            height += dragAmount.y.toDp()
                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            height = 0.dp
                            width = 0.dp
                        }
                    )
                },
            color = colorResource(id = Color.Blue),
            width = width.value,
            height = height.value,
            offsetX = offsetX,
            offsetY = offsetY,
        )
    }
}

